# How to find an unknown average in a set of data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Suppose that i have two set of data with 150 cells, Set A and Set B. The average of first 60 cells of set A is calculated, which is defined with letter C (it is a value). Then, Set B is equals to set A - C. for example:  B1=A1-C, B2=A2-C, and so on.
Then, set B is calculated. 
If someone has only set B of data, how to calculate that average (C) number? supposing he/she don't know C number and only has Set B?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to solve your homework by yourself before asking? What did you try?

Comment: I tried "moving average" but didn't help. Set B data is a set of data aquired from a satellite that measures earth's gravity. I want to find C number to have original data.

Comment: Clearly C is defined from A, so you can get A from B and C, or you could get C from A, but there is no clear way to get C only from B.

Comment: Suppose that i have only B dataset. Is it possible to calculate either set A or C value?

Comment: No. The value of B can be any combination of A and C. Suppose you have B1 equal to 2. This can be A1 equal of 4 with C equal to 2, or 6 with 4, and so on.

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to mathematics section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it appears you only have Set B; you don't have Set A or the number C.

Since the relation is defined as A<sub>index</sub> - C = B<sub>index</sub>, this is clearly a two-variable equation of a = x - y, where x and y are variables. Every high-school student knows that this equation has infinite answers.

**Short answer:** You have insufficient data to calculate A.

Comment: That's true, i said my professor before it is impossible to calculate A or C. If i want to add a new equation in order to solve this problem, a new unknown variable is also added. Therefore, there will be infinite C and also A. Thanks for your answer